# Adobe CQ5 regex that will reject an entire string if either of 2 different substrings are found within the string

Tags: regex, dialog, editor, adobe, aem

Adobe CQ5 dialog editor, regex property:

I am regex challenged so forgive me, but it seems a simple task and I just can't seem to find the right fit elsewhere on the internet. Every suggestion that looks right just doesn't seem to work in adobe's regex field.

I want the content admin to supply a relative URL to a "thank you" page. I don't need anything super fancy, I simply want to reject the admin's input if "http" or ".com" is found anywhere within the text supplied by the admin.

```
Examples for admin supplied input:
URL                                       REGEX VALIDATES INPUT AS SUCCESS?
http://www.domain.com/questions           No. string has both "http" and ".com"
https://www.domain.com/mail               No. string has both "http" and ".com"
https://www.domain.net                    No. string has "http"
oopshttp://www.domain.net                 No. string has "http"
www.domain.com/mail                       No. string has ".com"
/subdomain/thankyou.html                  YES! string has neither "http" or ".com"
```

Ideally, the rejection of "http" and ".com" would supplement what I currently have: Which is the string must start with a forward slash "/" and end in ".html" which is:

```
/^\/.+?\.html$/
```

Any help is appreciated, thank You in advance

Comment: A simple alternation `http|\.com` should work.

Comment: /http|\.com/ rejects everything I type into the field, so no go. I don't know if different systems are finicky about regex - all I can offer is that it's adobe CQ5's dialog editor regex

Comment: Well, a regection is what you want right? If the outcome is a non-match, then its a sucess. Can you change the validation to fail = pass? Well try one of Jerry's or mine regex's, if it accepts it, your good to go.

Comment: Hey, you got it working with the same style regex Jerry and I posted. I know you don't know about regex's but a little info for you. The regex you edited/listed above `/^\/.+?\.html$/` is not actually a valid regex. That regex looks for a slash.BOL.any chars,dot,html,EOS,slash. Its impossible for that to match anything. When you post regex's you should post ones that actuall work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can work with negative lookahead:

```
^\/(?!.*?(http|\.com)).+?\.html$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/dN8uV2

Comment: This appears to only answer the extra credit question and not the main question - which is really what I need help with.

Comment: If you see demo link I provided it has all the inputs from your main question also.

Comment: Winner winner, you totally rock! Thank you! Adobe CQ5 likes the regex from your demo and it seems to be working solid. Enjoy your well earned weekend!

Comment: There is no reason to escape the forward slash, as the regex engine doesen't consider it a special character. And there is no reason for non-greedy quantifiers.

Comment: @sin: Wish you try things before writing your comments. Try unescaped forward slash in Javascript `String#match` method and then report.

Comment: Hey anbava, the OP never listed java script and neither did you. You posted a **raw** regex. If you know regular expressions you know that the _forward_ slash is never a special character that needs to be escaped in any language. If you're going to specify a language, state so then show a delimited version of the regex and or code, or show a raw regex in proper form. Nobody's a mind reader here. And I stand by my comment.

Comment: Escaping doesn't hurt the outcome but unescaping makes it invalid esp. when underlying regex is unknown. A so called raw regex should work on any any regex engine isn't it? You can stand by your comment for eternity, don't think it matters.

Answer (score 2):

`^/.+\.html$` should work completely fine.

**Autopsy**:

- `^` *the start MUST match whatever is next:*
- `/` *a literal slash (if your modifier is a slash you need to escape this to `\/`*)
- `.+` *match as much as possible (any character 1 to infinity times)*
- `\.html` *the literal string `.html`*
- `$` *the end MUST be here*

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wLavoRRt5ZKhPizZ)

Comment: This appears to only answer the extra credit question and not the main question - which is really what I need help with.

Comment: What actually works in adobe cq5 for the extra credit is /^\/.+?\.html$/

Comment: @user3474152 It's a lot easier to have to match something rather than having to *not* match something.