# Changing Regex to Exclude http://

Tags: regex

This Regex works great for converting URL's to lower case:

Search for...

```
(?<=(?i)href=")((?:<\?php(?:(?!\?>).)+\?>)?)((?:'[^']+')?)([^"]+)(?=")
```

Replace with...

```
\1\2\L\3
```

I think it might be a GREP; it works with TextWrangler but not Dreamweaver.

Anyway, I wondered if anyone knows how I can modify it so it ignores URL's that begin with http://. I only want to modify local links, which generally look like any of the following:

```
<a href="/World/Spain" title="Topics">Spain</a>
<a href="$G_URL/World/Spain" title="Spain">Spain</a>
<a href="'.$G_URL.'/World/Spain" title="Spain">Spain</a>
```

Comment: Might you be looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22723176/247893)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
(?<=(?i)href=")(?!http://)((?:<\?php(?:(?!\?>).)+\?>)?)((?:'[^']+')?)([^"]+)(?=")
```

You could even remove the `://`

```
(?<=(?i)href=")(?!http)((?:<\?php(?:(?!\?>).)+\?>)?)((?:'[^']+')?)([^"]+)(?=")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=(?i)href=")(?!http)((?:<\?php(?:(?!\?>).)+\?>)?)((?:'[^']+')?)([^"]+)(?=")
```

demo here :

http://regex101.com/r/kZ3tO9